# Python Exceptions difficulty

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a lab soon but I am having difficulty, the prompt is:

A pedometer treats walking 2,000 steps as walking 1 mile. Write a steps_to_miles() function that takes the number of steps as a parameter and returns the miles walked. The steps_to_miles() function throws a ValueError object with the message "Exception: Negative step count entered." when the number of steps is negative. Complete the main() program that reads the number of steps from a user, calls the steps_to_miles() function, and outputs the returned value from the steps_to_miles() function. Use a try-except block to catch any ValueError object thrown by the steps_to_miles() function and output the exception message.

Output each floating-point value with two digits after the decimal point, which can be achieved as follows:
print('{:.2f}'.format(your_value))

I have been working on it for awhile now, my code is:

```
def steps_to_miles():

  steps = int(input())

     if steps < 0:

        raise ValueError

    return steps

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        steps = steps_to_miles()
        
        miles_walked = float(steps / 2000)
        print('{:.2f}'.format(miles_walked))
    
    except ValueError:
        print('Exception: Negative step count entered.')
```

(Sorry for formatting errors...) The code runs but is only giving me 4 out of the 10 points due to Zybooks stating "test_passed function missing" and "Test stepsToMiles(-3850), should throw an exception". What am I missing or how can fix it? Or alternatively is there another way to write the code?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Since you're working in Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning of your code. If your code was really indented like this, it would give you an indentation error and wouldn't pass any tests. Perhaps you could [edit] it to a [mre].

Comment: If the grader is telling you that your code should throw an exception for negative values, then you shouldn't catch that exception with an `except`: just let the exception be raised.

Comment: Read again carefully what the assignment ask you to do. More or less the only thing that is in accordance with the assignment is the name of the function `steps_to_miles()`. Although it is not certain as the message suggests it expects `stepsToMiles` (but this may not be the case).

Answer (score 0):

```
def steps_to_miles(steps):
  
    if steps < 0:

        raise ValueError

    return float(steps / 2000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    steps = int(input()) 

    try:
        miles_walked = steps_to_miles(steps)
    
    except ValueError:
        print('Exception: Negative step count entered.')

    print('{:.2f}'.format(miles_walked))
```

1. in body of try, need use only 'danger' code
2. your function was unworked becourse: you dont send any parameter, and it dont return value
3. `input` moved into `main` . It was next error: steps was local variable, which dont used in global namespace, and in function `main`

Answer (score 0):

We can't do a lot to help you with an automatic homework grader, you should probably ask your teacher or TA. Here are a few pointers:

- Your `steps_to_miles` does not take any arguments, according to the assignment it should take a single integer argument.
- The `ValueError` you throw does not have a message attached to it.
- `steps_to_miles` should divide its argument by 2000 but it doesn't do so. Instead you divide by 2000 outside of the function.
- You print a specific string in your `except` block instead of printing the exception's actual message.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make your error message a variable, in regards to your zyBooks giving you this error: "Test stepsToMiles(-3850).

I would try this in your function: `raise ValueError('Exception: Negative step count entered.')`
I would also write in this in your final "except" statement.

```
except ValueError as err:
     print(err)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
def steps_to_miles(num_steps):
    if num_steps < 0:
        raise ValueError("Exception: Negative step count entered.")
    return num_steps / 2000
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_steps = int(input())
    try:
        num_miles = steps_to_miles(num_steps)
        print('{:.2f}'.format(num_miles))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```